# Clicked 2 Button At Once

Tags: c#

Hello :) I Actually want to ask something 
So my aim here is "If I click the button 1, the button 2 will be clicked too "

"Is it possible ? Click a one button so the other button will be clicked ?"

Here is my Code:

```
Button btn1 = sender as Button;

if (btn1 == button1){
    button2.PerformClick();
}
```

It actually does not work it seems there is something wrong

Comment: Do you really want to click the second button or do you just want to execute the cuntion which is behind the second button?

Comment: Yeah i want also want to execute behind :v

Comment: Answering an "or" question with yes is funny :)
You want to exeute the code from the the button2 onClick method when clicking button1, too? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes :) @Mighty Badaboom

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *extracting methods*.

Before:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Routine 1 code ...
  Routine 2 code ... // <- do not copy yourself; copy + paste is evil!
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Routine 2 code ...
}
```

After:

```
//TODO: think over the right name
private void Routine1() 
{ 
  Routine 1 code ...
}

//TODO: think over the right name 
private void Routine2() 
{ 
  Routine 2 code ...
}

...

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Routine1();
  Routine2();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Routine2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Button) == button1)
        {
            button2_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a weird reason for doing this, don't!

You should prefer something like this :

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWork1();
    DoWork2();
}

void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoWork2();
}
```